# Two different Listviews in one Activity, only one gives right ItemClicks

Tags: android, listview, onitemclick

I have two listviews on one activity, everything is working fine, but if I want to get the clicked items from listview 1 and listview 2 I can only get the items from listview 1

activity_smokes:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollojt"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        >
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5">
        </ListView>

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/listView"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_weight=".50"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

smokes:

```
CustomAdapter adapter, adapterCT;
public  smokes CustomListView = null;
public  ArrayList<ListModel> CustomListViewValuesArr = new ArrayList<ListModel>();
public  ArrayList<ListModel> CustomListViewValuesArrCT = new ArrayList<ListModel>();
String[] Difficulties = {"Easy", "Medium", "Hard", "Very Hard"};
String Map;
String value;

private enum Maps {
    Cobblestone, Chache, Dust, Inferno, Mirage, Overpass, Train;
}



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_smokes);

    Map = getIntent().getStringExtra("Map");
    Maps abc= Maps.valueOf(Map);

    if(Map.equals("Dust")){
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Dust 2");
    } else {
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(Map);
    }


    CustomListView = this;

    switch(Map) {
        case Cobblestone:
            setListData()
    }


     Resources res =getResources();
    ListView listCT = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    adapterCT=new CustomAdapter(CustomListView, CustomListViewValuesArrCT,res);
    listCT.setAdapter( adapterCT);

    listCT.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            ListModel tempValuesCT = (ListModel) CustomListViewValuesArrCT.get(position);
            Toast.makeText(smokes.this,
                    "" + tempValuesCT.getSmokeName(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    });


    ListView list= ( ListView )findViewById( R.id.listView1 );  // List defined in XML ( See Below )

    /**************** Create Custom Adapter *********/
    adapter=new CustomAdapter( CustomListView, CustomListViewValuesArr,res );
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            ListModel tempValues = (ListModel) CustomListViewValuesArr.get(position);
            Toast.makeText(smokes.this,
                    "" + tempValues.getSmokeName(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    });

}

public void setListData()
{
    ListModel lmT = new ListModel("Banana to CT Cross", "i0", Difficulties[0]);
    CustomListViewValuesArr.add(lmT);
    lmT = new ListModel("Banana to Coils","i1",Difficulties[1]);
    CustomListViewValuesArr.add(lmT);
    lmT = new ListModel("Second Mid to Long","i3",Difficulties[1]);
    CustomListViewValuesArr.add(lmT);
    lmT = new ListModel("Second Mid to Short","i4",Difficulties[1]);
    CustomListViewValuesArr.add(lmT);

    ListModel lmCT = new ListModel("A Pit to Short", "i2", Difficulties[1]);
    CustomListViewValuesArrCT.add(lmCT);
    lmCT = new ListModel("A Long to Mid", "i5", Difficulties[1]);
    CustomListViewValuesArrCT.add(lmCT);
}




 /********* Adapter class extends with BaseAdapter and implements with OnClickListener ************/
static class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    /*********** Declare Used Variables *********/
    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public Resources res;
    ListModel tempValues=null;
    int i=0;

    /*************  CustomAdapter Constructor *****************/
    public CustomAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList d,Resources resLocal) {

        /********** Take passed values **********/
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        res = resLocal;

        /***********  Layout inflator to call external xml layout () ***********/
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.
                getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }

    /******** What is the size of Passed Arraylist Size ************/
    public int getCount() {

        if(data.size()<=0)
            return 1;
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    /********* Create a holder Class to contain inflated xml file elements *********/
    public static class ViewHolder{

        public TextView text;
        public TextView text1;
        public ImageView image;

    }

    /****** Depends upon data size called for each row , Create each ListView row *****/
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View vi = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;

        if(convertView==null){

            /****** Inflate tabitem.xml file for each row ( Defined below ) *******/
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabitem, null);

            /****** View Holder Object to contain tabitem.xml file elements ******/

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.text);
            holder.text1=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            holder.image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

            /************  Set holder with LayoutInflater ************/
            vi.setTag( holder );
        }
        else
            holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();

        if(data.size()<=0)
        {
            holder.text.setText("No Data");
            holder.text1.setText("No Data");

        }
        else
        {
            /***** Get each Model object from Arraylist ********/
            tempValues=null;
            tempValues = ( ListModel ) data.get( position );

            /************  Set Model values in Holder elements ***********/

            holder.text.setText( tempValues.getSmokeName() );
            holder.text1.setText( tempValues.getDifficulty() );
        }
        return vi;
    }
}
```

}

**EDIT:**
I updated the code, it's working now for me!

Comment: ListView inside a ScrollView?  That's asking for trouble.

Comment: That's a good point, but it won't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that you are using different datasets to populate your listviews but in `onItemClick` you are fetching the data from only one of the datasets although you are selecting an item from any of the listviews.

**First  List uses "CustomListViewValuesArrCT" dataset**

```
ListView listCT = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
  adapterCT=new CustomAdapter(CustomListView, CustomListViewValuesArrCT,res);
  listCT.setAdapter( adapterCT);
```

**Second List uses "CustomListViewValuesArr" dataset**

```
 ListView list= ( ListView )findViewById( R.id.listView1 ); 
    adapter=new CustomAdapter( CustomListView, CustomListViewValuesArr,res );
    list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

**BUT
Fetching data only from "CustomListViewValuesArr" in either list item selection .**

```
      public void onItemClick(int mPosition)
        {
           // You are fetching value from "CustomListViewValuesArr" only 
            ListModel tempValues = ( ListModel ) CustomListViewValuesArr.get(mPosition); 

    .....
        }
```

You need to fix your flow so that upon list item click  you fetch the data from that dataset using which you set the adapter for that particular list.

Comment: Oh, I forgot about this, thank you very much, but how can I get the listView which was clicked, like,   You clicked item 4 on listview 2. I thought about a onTouchListener or something like that, but I think there's more simple way

Comment: Why don't you "setOnItemClickListener()" for each ListView. Then there won't be any issues.

Comment: list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                ListModel tempValues = (ListModel) CustomListViewValuesArr.get(position);
                Toast.makeText(smokes.this,
                        "" + tempValues.getSmokeName(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
        });                                                           this doesn't work for a single one

Comment: You have to do this for both listviews but with the different dataset.

Comment: I did it with both, but it doesnt work for listview 1 and listview 2

Comment: Now tell me for which list , you are able to see the Toast and for which you aren't .

Comment: And try removing ScrollView . That's not needed.

Comment: I already removed the ScrollView, and I'm not able to see a Toast

Comment: Maybe it can help, in the first listview I have 4 items, and in the second lv i have 2, but if i click on the third++ item in listview 1 it crashes with an IndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: You didn't removed  --  vi.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener( position )); from getView(). You have to remove it to make it work .

Comment: Now it works, I really appreciate your help! Thank you very much!